# Output XMLWriter to XML file

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I am currently using XMLWriter to display an xml file. However I would like to know how I could export the output to a .xml file.

My current code is:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->startElement('stores');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
//loads of code
}
$xml->endElement();

$xml->flush();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a filename instead of `php://output` in the `openURI()` method.

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('test.xml');
$writer->startDocument("1.0");
$writer->startElement("greeting");
$writer->text('Hello World');
$writer->endDocument();
$writer->flush();
```

Comment: Do you know if is possible to create the directory if it doesn't exist?